# macOS (Catalina) Disabled Input Monitoring

Tags: macos, security, catalina, system-settings, privacy

I have an application that I need to add to the input monitoring section of Security/Privacy.  For some reason when I click on it and then unlock I don't even get an empty list, I get nothing and there's no more "+" to add to the list....

[image]

Comment: I wrote a guide for [screen recording permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384228/18101) that might help you because the rules are very similar. Basically you need to run the app first and try to start Input Monitoring before it will appear in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak specifically for that list as I'm still on Mojave, but there are several like that [Microphone & Camera on Mojave]. The app must ask, there is no user 'add' function at all.

That **is** the empty list, it won't become a true list until it is populated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this with Logitech Options. It wasn't showing up in **Input Monitoring**. To fix this, I had to see where else it was and remove it. Then reboot.

In my case, I found Logi Options and Logi Options Daemon in **Accessibility**.

1. Click the lock icon
2. Enter admin password
3. Select the app to remove
4. Click the minus sign (-) button
5. Repeat for other related apps
6. Reboot

Now, when you log back into macOS, you will be prompted to allow the new permissions. This should add the app to Input Monitoring.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I found screenshots from other ppl displaying that manually adding apps/files to the input monitor should work but maybe there needs to be at least one app in the list for it to display the add function (via +)?

This really sucks as this seems to be the last area I need to add a file for my wacom tablet to finally work again. Wacom support says, I need to add the driver in the input monitor.